# Как получить полный путь к файлу с несколькими вложенностями python os

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, ос

Есть структура папок:

```
главная папка
----вложенная папка
--------третьего уровня
------------файл
------------файл
------------файл
------------файл
--------третьего уровня
----вложенная папка
--------третьего уровня
```

По факту их значительно больше.
В папках третьего уровня хранятся файлы, с которыми надо осуществить взаимодействие.

На данный момент не придумал ничего лучшего, чем спарсить полные пути к файлам и через них напрямую обратиться.

Есть такой код:

```
main_dir = '...path...' #урл главной папки
in_main = os.listdir(main_dir) #список всех вложенных папок
for i in in_main:
    third = os.listdir(i) #третьего уровня
        for i in third:
            file_path = os.path.abspath(i)  # Не отрабатывает
            file_path = os.path.dirname(i)  # Не отрабатывает
```

В общем, не удаётся никаким образом получить родительскую папку конечных файлов

Comment: Пробовали использовать `os.walk` или `glob.glob`?

Comment: Пробовал os.walk, но чтобы обработать выводимое - нужно достаточно много дополнительных операций, которые для меня на текущий момент непонятны

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте, например, [glob.glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob).

Например, у меня есть `src`, в ней папки, а в них `js`-файлы.

В нотации [wildcard](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0) для [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) это:

```
from glob import glob
from os.path import abspath

for file_name in glob('src/*/*.js'):
    print(file_name, '->', abspath(file_name))
```

Результат

```
src\js\jquery-3.1.1.min.js -> D:\<path>\src\js\jquery-3.1.1.min.js
```

---

Это будет работать и для более четкого пути поиска: `'src/js/*.js'` и для менее четкого: `'*/*/*.js'` (при желании, с python 3.5, можно указать рекурсивный путь через `**` и флаг в `glob`).

Если формат неизвестен, то можно не указывать расширение файла: `'src/*/*'`, но понадобится делать проверки

Comment: Спасибо за ответ,
glob только для unix, насколько понял :(

Comment: @ptpwork, на виндовс тоже заработает (я на ней и работаю)

Comment: @gil9red, судя по документации, `**` работает только начиная с Python 3.5. Если ставите вопросу метки версий, то тогда и ответ стоит давать с учетом разных версий (указывать, что какая-то функциональность доступна только с определенной версии). Или не ставить метку Python 2 везде.

Comment: @insolortiredofthisdrama, спасибо

Comment: @gil9red, в общем, сделал с применением glob, оказалось, эта задача действительно решается в 2 строчки.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Чуть позже протестирую через glob, на данный момент нашёл временное решение без него, но оно не совсем корректно:

```
def get_folders_list():
    folder = 'PATH'
    folders = os.listdir(folder)
    for i in folders:
        if '.' not in i:
            last_fold = [i]
            for i in last_fold:

                l_f_path = os.path.abspath(i)

                for i in os.listdir(l_f_path):
                    links = l_f_path + '\\' + i
                    print(links)
```

Оно не совсем корректно, т.к. я уменьшил уровень вложенности до 1. В моём проекте это допустимо, но это не масштабируется.

С чем может быть связано такое поведение python? (что он видит не глубже одной папки)
Или я прописываю некорректный алгоритм?

Буду признателен за ответы или рекомендации источников